# Assigning a function with parameters to variable, how to get a specific value from a variable

Tags: php, html, sql, xml

There is one function called `getEvents` that looks like

```
function getEvents($numOfItems = 500, $query = array(), 
                   $output = null, $ignoreID = false)
```

which would return the output of events including date, infos, titels etc.
And in the other file, I have

```
$linkXml = getEvents(2, array(), 'xml');
```

Now the question is, how do I get a specific value `month` from this `$linkXML`?

Comment: Knowing what code is actually in the getEvents() function might just help us answer this

Comment: `var_dump($linkXml)` to see what's in the variable.. from there, you should be able to determine if it's an `object` or `array`. If it's an object, you could potentially access via `$linkXml->month`, if it's an array, you could potentially access via `$linkXml['month']`. It really depends on the TYPE and HIERARCHY of the data.